# Why would a GFCI receptacle causes my electric tools to run slow?

Tags: electrical

I recently had an outdoor GFCI receptacle installed, but it  causes my electric tools to run slow (hedge clippers, etc.).

Do I need to increase the amps rating, if so to what?

Comment: Are you sure it's the outlet and not the hedge clippers?  If so, my only guess would be that the receptacle was installed in series rather than in parallel.  This would drop a significant drop in voltage *(though, I think a good GFCI should trip for that case - check the voltage with a multimeter)*.  It could possibly be that the outlet is broken, or there is an arc/short somewhere, too.

Comment: Is this a new instalation? Was there an existing outlet in that location that worked fine?

Comment: What make/model of hedge clipper is it?  It is very hard to imagine that even a humongous hedge clipper would require more power than a standard outlet could provide.

Comment: @wallyk, it was a big twig!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the voltage at the appliance is reduced when the motor is running. This happens when the wire length exceeds the maximum limit for the expected current. Said another way, the voltage drop on the line between the breaker and the GFCI is too great for that amount of current. This suggests the wire size is too small (e.g., 12 ga vs 10 ga). If a light load (100W bulb, radio, etc.) is plugged in, does it work as expected?